# C struct array and search: Attempting to a match a member and prnt the entire struct if a match is found.

Tags: c, search, struct, printf

here is the struct

```
int main() {
    typedef struct {
        char firstName[25];
        char lastName[30];
        char street[35];
        char city[20];
        char state[3];
        int zip;
        char phone[15];
        int accountId;
    }Customer ;
```

say i fill this out with x amount of data.

what is a simple way to search the array index of this struct based on one its members, and then print that "Customers" info. Specifically I am looking to search for customers by state.

Comment: I have been trying to use scanf and to read users input.. then prinf but I am completely lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example that I believe will be of some help.  Of course, the Customer definition, record printing, and data population need to be expanded.  Also note that customer[] is on the stack in this example, so its members aren't zeroed and hence should be set to intended values one way or another.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_RECORDS   10

int main()
{
    int i;
    typedef struct {
        char state[3];
    } Customer;

    Customer customer[NUM_RECORDS];
    strcpy(customer[2].state, "CA");

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_RECORDS; i++)
    {
        // if this customer record's state member is "CA"
        if (!strcmp(customer[i].state, "CA"))
            printf("state %d: %s\n", i, customer[i].state);
    }

    // Prints "state 2: CA"

    return 0;
}
```